# How to fetch Kafka Stream and print it in Spark Shell?

Tags: scala, shell, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

First I built an SBT in a folder in the following way

```
val sparkVersion = "1.6.3"                                                                                                                           
scalaVersion := "2.10.5"                                                                                                                             
resolvers += "Spark Packages Repo" at "https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven"                                                                  
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(                                                                                                                         
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion,                                                                                              
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka" % sparkVersion                                                                                         
 )                                                                                                                                                   
libraryDependencies +="datastax" % "spark-cassandra-connector" % "1.6.3-s_2.10"                                                                      
libraryDependencies +="org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.1.0"
```

Later in the same folder where my ***"build.sbt"*** exists I started the spark shell in following way

```
 >/usr/hdp/2.6.0.3-8/spark/bin/spark-shell --packages datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:1.6.3-s_2.10 --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=127.0.0.1
```

These are the warnings shown while spark shell is started:

---

```
WARN AbstractLifeCycle: FAILED SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:4040: java.net.Bind
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
WARN AbstractLifeCycle: FAILED org.spark-project.jetty.server.Server@75bf9e67:
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

---

In Spark shell am importing the following packages

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf; import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext; import org.apache.spark.streaming.Seconds; import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils; import com.datastax.spark.connector._ ; import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._ ;
```

Then in spark shell creating a configuration in the below way:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("KafkaReceiver").set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true").setMaster("local");
```

After creating configuration assigning it, created a new spark streaming context in the below way:

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(10))
```

During the creation of spark streaming context the few warnings which are shown above raised again along with other warning, as shown below

---

```
WARN AbstractLifeCycle: FAILED SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:4040: java.net.Bind
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
.
.
.
WARN AbstractLifeCycle: FAILED org.spark-project.jetty.server.Server@75bf9e67:
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
.
.
.
WARN SparkContext: Multiple running SparkContexts detected in the same JVM!                                                        
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243). To ignore this error, set spark.driver.allowMulti
pleContexts = true. The currently running SparkContext was created at:                                                                               
org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:82)                                                                                          
org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.createSparkContext(SparkILoop.scala:1017)
.
.
.
WARN StreamingContext: spark.master should be set as local[n], n > 1 in local mode if you have receivers to get data, otherwise Spa
rk jobs will not get resources to process the received data.                                                                                         
ssc: org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext = org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext@616f1c2e
```

---

Then using created spark streaming context created a kafkaStream in the below way

```
val kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, "localhost:2181","spark-streaming-consumer-group", map("spark-topic" -> 5))
```

Then printing the stream and starting the ssc in below way

```
kafkaStream.print()
ssc.start
```

After use of the above command in shell the output is as shown in the below images

[image: Image1- Eariler part of output]

[image: Image2 - after fetching Jars & connecting to zookeeper]

[image: Issues came across in zookeeper]

Later starts the following mess ! of stream without printing values but information just as shown in below image [image: Final output]

Output that's getting printed repeatedly is here as shown below !

---

```
17/08/18 10:01:30 INFO JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1503050490000 ms.0 from job set of time 1503050490000 ms                             
17/08/18 10:01:30 INFO JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1503050490000 ms.0 from job set of time 1503050490000 ms                             
17/08/18 10:01:30 INFO JobScheduler: Total delay: 0.003 s for time 1503050490000 ms (execution: 0.000 s)                                             
17/08/18 10:01:30 INFO BlockRDD: Removing RDD 3 from persistence list                                                                                
17/08/18 10:01:30 INFO KafkaInputDStream: Removing blocks of RDD BlockRDD[3] at createStream at <console>:39 of time 1503050490000 ms                
17/08/18 10:01:30 INFO ReceivedBlockTracker: Deleting batches ArrayBuffer(1503050470000 ms)                                                          
17/08/18 10:01:30 INFO InputInfoTracker: remove old batch metadata: 1503050470000 ms                                                                 
17/08/18 10:01:30 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 3                                                                                                  
17/08/18 10:01:40 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1503050500000 ms                                                                            
-------------------------------------------                                                                                                          
Time: 1503050500000 ms                                                                                                                               
-------------------------------------------
```

---

Comment: Can you paste output here? I am not able to open the images due to access restriction. :(

Comment: @VinodChandak those are 1000's of lines ! I think it would be a mess if I paste here ! Can you let me know any other alternative way to provide you output !

Comment: Edited the question output of the finale part is added below all images @VinodChandak Hope you would go through it and help me out if possible!

Comment: I dont see any exception here. The code looks perfect. You can try adding one last statement.      ssc.awaitTermination() for waiting the termination.

Comment: In addition to that, dont print the stream itself, Try to persist the kafkaStream (DStream) to file system. You can use DStream.foreachRDD method for that. I can post a sample if you want.

Comment: @VinodChandak doubt here is can't I print the live stream ? 
I will be thankful you can post the sample for me ! Regards in Advance!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152276/discussion-between-ashrithgande-and-vinod-chandak).

Answer (score 1):

```
WARN AbstractLifeCycle: FAILED SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:4040: java.net.Bind   
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

It means that port which needs is already in use. As a rule, port 4040 is used by Spark-thrifteserver. So try to stop thriftserver using stop-thriftserver.sh from spark/sbin folder. Or check who else use this port and free it.

Comment: Tried that thing you said! Before starting spark shell ! No issues occurred! But once I started spark shell and have to create one more spark context same exception raised again! I tried to kill that process, then execution closed ! Because process associated to it is java ! 

As they are just warnings, I think it doesn't effect execution much! But Main issue why stream fetched was not able to get printed on screen!

Comment: Usage of multiple Spark contexts is discouraged and really bad idea.
You can stop an existing SparkContext using sc.stop() method and after that create a new one. 
Also, you can use an existing SparkContext using getOrCreate(conf)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by doing the following things:

1. Take care of case sensitivity, because Scala is case sensitive language.
   In below part of code used map() instead of Map()

***`val kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, "localhost:2181","spark-streaming-consumer-group", map("spark-topic" -> 5))`*** wrong practice! That is the reason why spark couldn't fetch your stream !

***`val kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, "localhost:2181","spark-streaming-consumer-group", Map("spark-topic" -> 5))`*** right practice!

2. Check if producer is streaming to Kafka topics mentioned in the map function! Spark couldn't fetch your stream from topic mentioned, either when Kafka-producer streaming data to that topic is stopped or when the data in streaming is finished, spark starts removing RDD from array buffer and displays the message as below!

---

```
17/08/18 10:01:30 INFO JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1503050490000 ms.0 from job set of time 1503050490000 ms                             
17/08/18 10:01:30 INFO JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1503050490000 ms.0 from job set of time 1503050490000 ms                             
17/08/18 10:01:30 INFO JobScheduler: Total delay: 0.003 s for time 1503050490000 ms (execution: 0.000 s)                                             
17/08/18 10:01:30 INFO BlockRDD: Removing RDD 3 from persistence list                                                                                
17/08/18 10:01:30 INFO KafkaInputDStream: Removing blocks of RDD BlockRDD[3] at createStream at <console>:39 of time 1503050490000 ms                
17/08/18 10:01:30 INFO ReceivedBlockTracker: Deleting batches ArrayBuffer(1503050470000 ms)                                                          
17/08/18 10:01:30 INFO InputInfoTracker: remove old batch metadata: 1503050470000 ms                                                                 
17/08/18 10:01:30 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 3                                                                                                  
17/08/18 10:01:40 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1503050500000 ms                                                                            
-------------------------------------------                                                                                                          
Time: 1503050500000 ms                                                                                                                               
-------------------------------------------
```

---

3. Follow the comments and response of @YehorKrivokon and @VinodChandak to avoid the warnings faced!

Answer (score 0):

Kind of late, but this could help somebody else. Spark shell already instantiates SparkContext, which is available as sc. So to create StreamingContext, just pass the existing sc as argument. Hope this helps!